# NPM private packages custom build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

We are using private npm packages for components. Is it possible to set up both minified and unminified bundles for these packages? Debugging these packages with minified code is complex. If we use mangle:false then package size will increase. Any suggestions regarding this?

Comment: Most code minifying tools have an option to generate a source map(s). If it's `uglify-js` you're using then utilize the [`--source-map`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js#command-line-options) option.

Comment: @RobC source map does not ease your life in this case. Once they are minified - you won't be able to find the component name in the component hierarchy.